# UNIX feed $PATH to find

Tags: unix, path, find

Is there any way I can search through all folders in my path for a file. Something like

```
for f in $PATH ; do ; find "$f" -print | grep lapack ; done
```

So that every folder in PATH is recursively searched for lapack

Comment: start at the root directory find /

Comment: I don't want to look recursively through all files on my computer. I only want to look recursively through files in $PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, I ran a few tests, seems to be working:

```
echo -n $PATH | xargs -d: -i find "{}" -name "*lapack*"
```

The `-n` in `echo` prevents it from writing a newline in the end (otherwise the newline would be passed as part of the last directory name to `find(1)`).

The `-d` in `xargs(1)` says that the delimiter is `:`. The `-i` makes it replace `{}` with the current path.

The rest is self-explanatory, I guess.